# With g++ is there a runtime setting to scramble freed memory with delete?

Tags: debugging, gcc, runtime, g++

Does anyone know how I can for the g++ or gcc runtime to scramble the ram where an object was after delete?  I have a theory that I'm using an object after it has been deleted but in practice it rarely crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline void operator delete(void* memblock) { //you custom stuff }` would override the global. I used to use this for security so that we could zero out the memory so its less likely to leak important information.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggesting running with valgrind - that'll tell you if you're accessing memory after freeing it.

Comment: Valgrind causes my game to crash.

Comment: Well - that might be due to the memory corruption you are trying to trace. Have you fixed all errors it reports before crashing?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `delete` for your object if you like.

Comment: Is there a more global solution?

Comment: inline void operator delete(void* memblock) { //you custom stuff } would override the global. The different methods for testing for memory leaks or even for security follow this methodology. From the security standpoint, they zero out that region of memory before freeing it.